# Unable to reference classes from JAR generated by openapi-generator-maven-plugin in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, maven, intellij-idea, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I am currently working on a Kotlin project where I'm using the [kotlin-spring generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/kotlin-spring/) from 'openapi-generator-maven-plugin' to generate classes from an OpenAPI specification. My workflow involves packaging the generated files into a JAR and adding it to an Azure artifact repository. In a different project, I've added this JAR as a dependency.

The issue I'm facing is that even though I can see the Kotlin files within the external library in Intellij, I am unable to reference these classes within my Kotlin code. It's as if they are not being recognized by Intellij or Maven.

This is the configuration of openapi-generator-maven-plugin in the pom.xml within the project which generates the JAR file:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.6.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <inputSpec>
                ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/api/project-api.yaml
          </inputSpec>
          <generatorName>kotlin-spring</generatorName>
          <output>${project.build.directory}/classes</output>      <!-- *1* -->
          <configOptions>
            <basePackage>ch.organization.project</basePackage>
            <apiPackage>ch.organization.project.api</apiPackage>
            <modelPackage>ch.organization.project.api.model</modelPackage>
            <configPackage>ch.organization.project.api.config</configPackage>
            <sourceFolder>.</sourceFolder>
            <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
            <modelNameSuffix>Dto</modelNameSuffix>
            <documentationProvider>none</documentationProvider>
            <enumPropertyNaming>UPPERCASE</enumPropertyNaming>
            <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
            <gradleBuildFile>false</gradleBuildFile>
          </configOptions>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

`*1*`: This locates the generated classes within *target/classes* instead of default *target/generated-sources*. Having the classes within classes makes them to be bundled within the JAR file. Without this, the generated classes won't even be visible within the external libraries.

This is how it looks like in my Kotlin project, which adds the JAR file as a dependency:

```
- External Libraries
  - Maven: ch.organisation.project:api:1.0.8-SNAPSHOT
    - api-1.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar
        .openapi-generator-ignore
        pom.xml
        README.md
      - .openapi-generator
          ...
      - api
          project-api.yaml
      - ch.organisation.project.api
          CatsApi                      // Interface
          ApiUtil                      // Object class
        - model
            Cat                        // Data class
            Colour                     // Enum
      - META-INF
        MANIFEST.MF
        - maven.ch.organisation.project.api
            pom.properties
            pom.xml
```

Interestingly, Intellij finds `ch.organisation.project.api.model` as a directory but with nothing in it to reference to.

I tried to invalidate the Caches, restart the IDE, set `gradleBuildFile=false`, use default `output` configuration, build the project even though Intellij complains.

When I add Cat into my Kotlin code, the error is `Unresolved reference: Cat`.

Comment: Would you be able to share the resulting JAR you are adding as a dependency (or a sample JAR with a similar structure), so I can reproduce the issue and suggest a way to address it?